# Asp.Net MVC 5 - Custom Authorize not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-authorization

I have the following controller with a custom authorize attribute:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Editor, Admin")]
public ActionResult Test()
{
       //...

}
```

Here is my custom authorize code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    private readonly string[] _allowedRoles;

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        _allowedRoles = roles;

    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");


        var user = httpContext.User;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (_allowedRoles.Length > 0 && !_allowedRoles.Any(user.IsInRole))
        {
            return false;
        }


        return true;

    }


}
```

The custom authorize is returning **true** for **even a user who is not an Editor or Admin**?

I think the issue is this:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Editor, Admin")]
```

I'm passing it as a string and I need to convert it to an array in my CustomAuthorize method???

Comment: Debug and step through the logic in your code. inspect `!_allowedRoles.Any(user.IsInRole)` depending on user `IsInRole` returns true by default

Comment: @Nkosi do i need to pass roles `params string[] roles` as a parameter or does authorize attribute already  have `Roles`.

Comment: when debugging, what type is User?

Comment: Also based on attribute constructor  try `[CustomAuthorize("Editor", "Admin")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current definition of the attribute makes no reference to the `Roles` property and also does not populate the `_allowedRoles` field.

This is why your attribute always returns `true`.

Review the rafactored logic of custom attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute {
    private readonly string[] _allowedRoles;

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles) {
        _allowedRoles = roles;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        var user = httpContext.User;
        if (user?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated) {
            if (isInRole(user, _allowedRoles)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Roles)) {
                var roles = Roles.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (isInRole(user, roles))
                    return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool isInRole(IPrincipal user, string[] roles) {
        return roles.Length > 0 && roles.Any(user.IsInRole);
    }
}
```

Which can be used like

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Editor, Admin")]
public ActionResult Test() {
       //...
}
```

where the roles will be split and checked against user

Or like

```
[CustomAuthorize("Editor", "Admin")]
public ActionResult Test() {
       //...
}
```

which would populate the constructor of the attribute with the parameter array

Answer (score 0):

first you need to get the current user's roles and then check if any of the roles allow the user to access to the controller :

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (httpContext == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");


    var user = httpContext.User;

    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var userRoles = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims
            .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
            .Select(c => c.Value);

    if (_allowedRoles.Length > 0 && !_allowedRoles.Any(x => userRoles.Any(y => x.Equals(y)))))
    {
        return false;
    }


    return true;

}
```

Comment: i'm not storing roles as a claim. I think I need to  split the roles into an array because I'm passing it as a string `[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Editor, Admin")]`. How do I split into array and remove any spaces between the comma delimiter the following doesn't work - `_allowedRoles = roles.Split(',');`?